# Spring boot custom OAuth Provider didn't return any response with status code 401

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, oauth-2.0

I try to write OAuth provider using spring boot but I got following issue, I using Postman using /oauth/token, but it return 401 Unauthorized and no response..

Here is example link I try to follow: https://codeaches.com/spring-cloud-security/oauth2-authorization-jdbc-token-store

In my requirement I need to use MS SQL Server database, so I follow the script in the link and try to convert to SQL Server script, and also here is the code part I try:

`WebSecurityConfig.java`

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    DataSource dataSource;


    @Override
    @Bean("userDetailsService")
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsServiceBean() throws Exception {
        return super.userDetailsServiceBean();
    }

    @Bean
    PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean("authenticationManager")
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {

        JdbcUserDetailsManagerConfigurer<AuthenticationManagerBuilder> cfg = auth.jdbcAuthentication()
            .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder()).dataSource(dataSource);

        cfg.getUserDetailsService().setEnableGroups(true);
        cfg.getUserDetailsService().setEnableAuthorities(false);
    }
}
```

`CustomTokenEnhancer.java`

```
public class CustomTokenEnhancer implements TokenEnhancer {

    @Override
    public OAuth2AccessToken enhance(OAuth2AccessToken accessToken, OAuth2Authentication authentication) {
        ((DefaultOAuth2AccessToken) accessToken).setTokenType("Bearer");

        return accessToken;
    }

}
```

`OAuth2AuthorizationServer`

```
@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
public class OAuth2AuthorizationServer extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    DataSource dataSource;

    @Bean
    public TokenStore tokenStore() {
        return new JdbcTokenStore(dataSource);
    }

    @Bean
    public TokenEnhancer tokenEnhancer() {
        return new CustomTokenEnhancer();
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {
        final TokenEnhancerChain tokenEnhancerChain = new TokenEnhancerChain();
        tokenEnhancerChain.setTokenEnhancers(Arrays.asList(tokenEnhancer()));
        endpoints.tokenStore(tokenStore()).authenticationManager(authenticationManager)
            .userDetailsService(userDetailsService);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer oauthServer) throws Exception {
        oauthServer.passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder).tokenKeyAccess("permitAll()")
            .checkTokenAccess("isAuthenticated()");
    }

}
```

I know some of codes are already depreciated, but in my requirement it cannot connect outside world (I don't think they want to open the firewall for that..)

Back to the question, does anything I miss?

Comment: Have you inserted the person's information to database?

Comment: @Gurkanİlleez yes I did. The only difference is because sql server doesn't have boolean type, it only have bit.. so for ```users``` table, when ```enabled``` in the article said ```true```, in my version become ```1```. I don't know  does this matter or not